# PascalScript: Looking for something like OnBeforeLineExec and OnAfterLineExec

Tags: delphi, pascalscript, remobjects

I am writing a small IDE with Single Steps using the Debugdemo.
Now I need an Event before and after a line is executed.
I would like to disable my Editor while the current Line is executed.
I found the OnLine Event but did not find out in what cases it is fired or how I can use it.
Any hints are welcome.

Greetings Klaus

Answer (score 0):

The `OnLine` event is meant to alter the interpretation of code.
It is not meant for debugging purposes.

If you want to do that use the `BreakPoints` in `TPSScriptDebugger`.
Put a breakpoint on the line and after the line.
Now you will get a signal before and after the line is executed.

Comment: Hello @Johan, 
thank you for answering.
Seems my desription was not as clear as possible.
I do not need breakpoints.

I would like to have kind of visual feedback that a line is currently beening executed (some of my functions need several seconds).
So the idea is (for example): 
- display a _running_ in the statubar when the user presses F8 and 
- display _stopped_ when the line is processed.

Comment: Yes, that's what a breakpoint would provide. If you have clarifications you should put them in your question, not scatter them around in comments :-)